# Undefined behaviour while swapping/exchanging pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I've created dynamic array. Filled if with certain values. Printing it. But after swapping/exchanging pointers (the task is to exchanging lines on certain conditions)

Conditions depend on `sumL`. I'm not describing detailes in order not to waste your time.

**The problem is in exchanging pointers.**

```
for ( k = 0; k < N - 1; k++ )
{
    for ( i = 0; i < N - 1; i++
       if (sumL[i] > sumL[i+1])
       {
           temp = sumL[i];            // works
           sumL[i] = sumL[i+1];
           sumL[i+1] = temp;

           temp = *a[i];              // doesn't work. Array is not the same: elements 
           a[i] = a[i+1];             // contain other values.
           *a[i+1] = temp;            /* What is wrong? */
      }
}
```

Comment: What are the variable types?  I'm surprised to see you dereference `a` only two of the four accesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swap pointers, then it should probably read

```
temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[i+1]; a[i+1] = temp;
```

If you want to swap values, then it should probably read

```
temp = *a[i]; *a[i] = *a[i+1]; *a[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: the 2-nd variant doean't swap swap the `pointers`...  Some elements change their value.

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot That's why he wrote "If you want to swap values" before the second variant.

Comment: Oh, understood!
  I'm new to C and apologize for my poor knowledge on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
*a[i] = *a[i+1];
```

Comment: That wouldn't swap the values, would it? It just shifts the values of the array.

Comment: Of course, that is supposed to be included at the right place, instead of `a[i] = a[i+1]`, not replace the whole block.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = *a[i];              //temp == value pointed by a[i], NOT pointer
a[i] = a[i+1];             // here you actually copy the pointer 
*a[i+1] = temp;            // here you again write value, NOT pointer
```

You should do:

```
type* temp_ptr = a[i];     
a[i] = a[i+1];
a[i+i] = temp_ptr;
```

Comment: I've made variable `temp` of type **pointer**. And it seems to be working... I have to verify the result..